# Serverless - Lambda Layers "Cannot find module 'request'"

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

When I deploy my serverless api using:

```
serverless deploy
```

The lambda layer gets created but when I go to run the function is gives me this error:

```
"Cannot find module 'request'"
```

But if I upload the .zip file manually through the console (the exactly same file thats uploaded when I deploy), it works fine.

Any one have any idea why this is happening?

```
environment:
SLS_DEBUG: "*"

provider:
name: aws
runtime: nodejs8.10
stage: ${opt:api-type, 'uat'}-${opt:api, 'payment'}
region: ca-central-1
timeout: 30
memorySize: 128
role: ${file(config/prod.env.json):ROLE}
vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
    - ${file(config/prod.env.json):SECURITY_GROUP}
    subnetIds:
    - ${file(config/prod.env.json):SUBNET}
apiGateway:
    apiKeySourceType: HEADER
apiKeys:
    - ${file(config/${opt:api-type, 'uat'}.env.json):${opt:api, "payment"}-APIKEY}

functions:
- '${file(src/handlers/${opt:api, "payment"}.serverless.yml)}'

package:
# individually: true
exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - nodejs/**

plugins:
- serverless-offline
- serverless-plugin-warmup
- serverless-content-encoding

custom:
contentEncoding:
    minimumCompressionSize: 0 # Minimum body size required for compression in bytes

layers:
nodejs:
    package:
    artifact: nodejs.zip
    compatibleRuntimes:
    - nodejs8.10
    allowedAccounts:
    - "*"
```

Thats what my serverless yaml script looks like.

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar error to you while using the explicit `layers` keys that you are using to define a lambda layer.

My error (for the sake of web searches) was this:

`Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module <package name>`

I feel this is a temporary solution b/c I wanted to explicitly define my layers like you were doing, but it wasn't working so it seemed like a bug.

I created a [bug report](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/6724) in Serverless for this issue. If anyone else is having this same issue they can track it there.

**SOLUTION**

I followed [this](https://forum.serverless.com/t/aws-lambda-layers-node-modules-not-working/7914) this post in the Serverless forums based on [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path) from AWS.

I zipped up my `node_modules` under the folder `nodejs` so it looks like this when it is unzipped `nodejs/node_modules/<various packages>`.

Then instead of using the explicit definition of layers I used the `package` and `artifact` keys like so:

```
layers:
  test:
    package:
      artifact: test.zip
```

In the function layer it is referred to like this:

```
functions:
  function1:
    handler: index.handler
    layers:
      - { Ref: TestLambdaLayer }
```

The `TestLambdaLayer` is a convention of `<your name of layer>LambdaLayer` as documented [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/layers#using-your-layers)

Comment: Not worked for me. Still error: `Error: Cannot find module './json.js'`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you run `npm install` inside your layers before deploying, ie:

```
cd ~/repos/repo-name/layers/utilityLayer/nodejs && npm install
```

Otherwise your layers will get deployed without a `node_modules` folder. You can download the .zip of your layer from the Lambda UI to confirm the contents of that layer.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone face a similar issue `Runtime.ImportModuleError`, is fair to say that another cause of this issue could be a package exclude statement in the `serverless.yml` file.

Be aware that if you have this statement:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - './**'
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!dist/**'
    - '.git/**'
```

It will cause exactly the same error, on runtime once you've deployed your lambda function (with serverless framework). Just, ensure to remove the ones that could create a conflict across your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I am using typescript with the `serverless-plugin-typescript` and I was having a same error, too.

When I switched from

```
const myModule = require('./src/myModule');
```

to

```
import myModule from './src/myModule';
```

the error disappeared. It seems like the files were not included into the zip file by `serverless` when I was using `require`.

PS: Removing the `serverless-plugin-typescript` and switching back to `javascript` also solved the problem.